# On URL, why is the anchor (#) after GET variable

Tags: url, variables, anchor

To display a defined element with an `id` on the linked page we insert the `#` with the id of the element.

E.g.:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/test/test.php#mydiv">DIV</a>
```

If we also include a/some `GET variables` on the link they must go before the `#` tag.

This works:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/test/test.php?a=1#mydiv">DIV</a>
```

This doesn't:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/test/test.php#mydiv?r=1">DIV</a>
```

Where is the reason?

Comment: Anything after isn't parsed and loaded into `$_GET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), the URI standard.

[3.5. Fragment](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.5):

> A fragment identifier component is indicated by the presence of a number sign ("#") character and **terminated by the end of the URI**.
>
> […]
>
> The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") are allowed to represent data **within** the fragment identifier.

So the fragment starts as soon as a `#` is found in the path. Everything after is part of the fragment. Therefore your last example has the following fragment: `mydiv?r=1`.

Answer (score 0):

The url standard demands that the anchor must be on the last position

The standard is

```
<protocol>://<host>:<port>/<path>?<query>#<anchor>
```

Many of the parts are optional but the order has to be maintained.